# Batch who rename a specifique file in a subfolder with the parentfolder name + extension

Tags: batch

I'm quite a noob in Dos and i'm trying to make a script (yeah)

What i'm trying to do is:

- Take the name of the folder where the batch is (example: .\Project_Apple*.bat)
- Rename a file in a subfolder with the name of the first one
  (example: `\Project_Apple\OUTPUT\template.txt` > `\Project_Apple\OUTPUT\Project_Apple.txt`)

For the rename and targeting, i dont have a problem. I use CD and REN. I've read that the FOR command can do it and read documentations about it but i dont find how to make it "remember" the folder name.

Is there a way to do it ?

EDIT:

I've make a huge step. I achieve to rename a file en the folder with the name of the folder with:

```
for %%i in (%cd%) do set CurrDirName=%%~nxi
rename test.txt %CurrDirName%
```

Now, i'm trying to targeting the file in the subfolder.

Comment: SuperUser is not a script writing service. Show us your research and what you've tried, then we're happy to help. But we won't just write a script for you

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved to do what i want with this.

```
for %%i in (%cd%) do set CurrDirName=%%~nxi
cd %CurrDir%\OUTPUT\
rename template.txt %CurrDirName%.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `%CD%` this is not neccessarily the folder the batch resides in.

- If invoking the batch with an absolute or relative path this doesn't change the current folder.
- To reference the currently running batch file with full path use `%~f0`
- extract the folder from that using a [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and `~` [modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\24\SU_1397868.cmd
@Echo off
Echo This batch file full path: %~f0
Echo This batch file drive    : %~d0
Echo This batch file path     : %~p0
Echo This batch file name     : %~n0

for %%A in (%0\..) Do Set folder=%%~nxA

Echo This batch file folder   : %folder%

If exist "%~dp0Output\template.txt" (
    Ren  "%~dp0Output\template.txt" "%folder%.txt"
)
```

Sample output on my ramdrive A:

```
> SU_1397868.cmd
This batch file full path: A:\Project_Apple\SU_1397868.cmd
This batch file drive    : A:
This batch file path     : \Project_Apple\
This batch file name     : SU_1397868
This batch file folder   : Project_Apple
```

---

```
> tree /F A:\
A:\
└───Project_Apple
    │   SU_1397868.cmd
    │
    └───OUTPUT
            Project_Apple.txt
```